# Output html headers from contentful includes a hidden svg with a link

Tags: gatsby, contentful

When I try to build my gatsby site sourcing from contentful, the html headers (i.e h1 elements) come with an "extra" svg element including an anchor tag, instead of just the header element that I intended to publish from contentful.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour when sourcing from contentful, and what would be the way forward if I just  want the header elements in my site and not the extra stuff that contentful is adding?

[image: contentful editor]
[image: gatsby body import from contentful]

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe they (contentful) can say better.

Answer (score 0):

The Contentful GraphQL API only returns the markdown string. It doesn't return HTML. The Markdown to HTML transformation is done by gatsby & plugins and only after the content was received.

Your example looks like the combined work of [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/) and [gatsby-remark-autolink-headers](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-autolink-headers/).

Removing "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers" from the list of configured plugins in your gatsby-config.js should get rid of the unwanted SVG tag.

---

To see what the Contentful API returns you can playing around with the GraphiQL editor for your particular space on the following page

```
https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/<YOUR SPACE ID>/explore?access_token=<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>
```

So when you take a look at our [example app](https://the-example-app-nodejs.contentful.com/) and [query one particular entry](https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/f8bqpb154z8p/explore?access_token=9d5de88248563ebc0d2ad688d0473f56fcd31c600e419d6c8962f6aed0150599&query=%7B%20lessonCopy(id:%223UVMv9wHuw4auWMQ0qSamY%22)%20%7B%20title%20copy%20%7D%20%7D) you get the raw markdown as a string.

[image: GraphQL result showing raw markdown string]

Comment: Thank you so much Harry, it was exactly that!